# Interbase SQL trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, interbase

Interbase, Sql, trigger. Can't really understand how to write a trigger of this kind: I have several tables. Each one has a document type, status and an unique number. One table in which i wish to create a trigger is a table that holds a file i post, a status of posting, a doctype corresponding to a table and a unique number linking to a record in the corresponding table. I want to change document status in the corresponding table based on the unique number to a certain status depending on the post result (status) that i change after posting. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger `T1` will be executed after update on `TABLE1`.

Trigger checks if `TABLE1.StatusOfPosting` changed to some value and depending on result updates `TABLE2.DocumentStatus`.

Depending on bussienes logic, maybe you will need and `BEFORE DELETE` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1 FOR TABLE1 AFTER UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.StatusOfPosting <> OLD.StatusOfPosting and NEW.StatusOfPosting=1) THEN
    UPDATE TABLE2
    SET TABLE2.DocumentStatus=1
    WHERE TABLE2.UniqueNumber = TABLE1.UniqueNumber;
END
```